# Issue using Relay mutations with files

Tags: react-native, relay, react-relay

I have an issue using File Mutation with Relay. I am trying to create a mutation using getFiles()

```
Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
  new AddOrderMutation({userId: userId, medications: OrderInputTypeMedication,
    userAddressId:userAddressId,files:files}),
  {
    onSuccess: (response) =>  OnResponseSuccess(response),
    onFailure: (transaction,e) => console.log('transaction',transaction.getError(),'e',e),
  },
);
```

}

I always get an error that said 
`transaction TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (D:\ReactNative\MedexApp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:436)`
although all other requests are working good. also the same mutation is sent correctly without attaching any files.
this is the array of files `["1489322712989.jpg":{filename:"1489322712989.jpg"
uri:"file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1489322712989.jpg"}]`
and It never sends the request through fiddler or caught in the webservice

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't adding to the Files Object (type: 'image/jpg'), so the file Object should be as follows:

```
file ={
         uri: this.state.image.uri,
         name: this.state.image.name,
         type:'image/jpg'
       };
```